# How do I calculate equally growing iteration equally between two numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I apologize if I do not have the terms correct. I am an artist and I am trying to calculate growth iterations between two numbers to insure correct mathematical growth in the design.

An Example may be I have an line $9$ inches long. I'd like to draw circles on this line starting with a small circle and ending with a larger circle. How do I calculate this to ensure each circle is larger by multiplying the size for each iteration?

please view [PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTiei.png) for reference. NOTE -  The shape can be anything it is the distance on the given line that is important. 
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: I suggest you draw something and upload the image to your question.

Comment: Will do thank you for the tip.

Comment: @WillJagy I added a photo. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you want the circles to have common tangent lines? There would be one along the top, touching all the circles. If so, your question does have a mathematical answer.

Comment: As shown using the red line in the graphic? If so then yes.

Comment: The red line will be used as a guide in a project. As long as the distant along the line is what we are talking about then I can use the formula to draw out the distances then use any shape since the distance will be mapped out. Does this make sense?

Comment: I posted an answer with additional lines in your diagram.

Answer (score 1):

As you say the repeated figure will not always be a circle, things change a little. The key point is that there will be a center point, which need not be visible in the final design. Draw your rightmost figure, then draw the figure immediately to its left, a bit smaller. Now draw in construction lines, a tangent line along the top, I used green, and a tangent line along the bottom, blue. The green, red, and blue lines meet at a point, this is the center of projection.

Along any one of the lines, the ratio of measured distances from the center gives the overall ratio $r.$ I used millimeters, the ratio here is $r \approx 215 / 265 \approx 0.811.$ Taking any straight line through the center, the distances to matching points in the first two figures should always be $r.$ If not, the figures are not really proportional.

To get the third figure, multiply everything in the second figure by $r$ again along any straight line through the center. This shows where the third figure goes. Keep drawing new figures until you have approximately your nine inches.

Do this enough times, either you will know how to do it yourself, or you will be able to ask a question with a more specific answer.

Mathematically, as Ross indicated, the initial setup is a fixed center point and one figure. Choose a fixed ratio $r$ and draw the second figure. If that is not what you want (I think you want the figures to touch) adjust $r.$

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant. In your construction, the first 2 circles (and the difference in diameters) determines the end of the line, the "center of projection." However, what if the OP drew the largest circle and then drew the blue and green lines to meet at the end of the line (original question stated the length of the line was known)? Would we be able to determine the rest of the circles that way?

Comment: @scott yes; a ratio $r$ is chosen to shrink the first figure, circle or whatever, to move it to the left and shrink it. I suspect the OP wants the figures to touch, although the tangent point may not be along the red line if the figures are less symmetric, such as an egg shape. In such a case, some experimentation with different $r$ may be required before rendering the final drawing.

Comment: @WillJagy - You are correct. The shapes will touch. BTW Thank you for your help this will help me move forward however, after posting my OP I realized I could draw the angled lines then draw the shapes inside the outer angled lines. This worked just fine but, I am glad I can put some math behind my design. I think it will make me a better designer and frankly I enjoy the refresher course in math as I have been out of Uni for a couple decades now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the diameter is multiplied by a common factor you have a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  If the first diameter is $a$, the ratio is $r$, and there are $n$ circles, the total length is $a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$  Choose the constants to make this the desired length.

Comment: I posted an answer, requesting clarification from the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ross Millikan.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the circles to be proportioned such that the blue line touches each circle at one point, and the green line touches each circle once?

[image]

Comment: Yes however, the blue and green lines angle may change depending on the design I am going for. It may not always be a circle, I may use an oval or elongated oval or another shape I have not used yet.

The graphic I included is not exact. I chucked it together in Photoshop to roughly show what I am going for. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: The important variable will be the middle line which is the length I work with on a project. My current project I have a space that is 9 inches long however, my next project I may have a 10 inch space to work with. The designs go on sphere shaped media which change in diameter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case for circles. It can be shown easily that the radius of consecutive circles form a geometric progression or GP. Let the radius of circles be $r_i$ where $i=1, 2, \cdots, N$. There are four variables:

- Length of line, $L$  (given)
- Number of circles, $N$
- Radius of first (smallest) circle, $a\; (<\frac L{2N})$
- Common ratio of GP, $\rho\; (>1)$

Hence
$$\begin{align}
L&=2(r_1+r_2+r_3+\cdots+r_N)\\
&=2a(1+\rho+\rho^2+\cdots+\rho^{N-1})\\
&=\frac {2a(\rho^N-1)}{\rho-1}\end{align}$$

**Using the example provided** we have $L=9, N=5$. Assuming we want $a=0.5$ ($<\frac L{2N}=0.9$, so OK), we have to find $\rho$ such that 
$$\frac {\rho^5-1}{\rho-1}=\frac 9{10}$$

Solving numerically gives $\rho=2.24497$.

So there are $5$ circles with radius starting from $0.1$, and the radius of a given circle is $2.24497$ times the previous smaller one.

Comment: Thank you @hypergeometric. This is very helpful and will be used in the future. :)